# わけない dual meanings: impossible vs easy

Tags: meaning, usage

I am struggling with those two possible meanings, and have found two examples that typically puzzle me:

1. 「この問題できる？」「こんなのわけないよ」
2. 「N2の試験に合格したんだって？」「そんなわけないだろう」

(taken from Nihongo So-Matome N2 book)

First one is given as holding the "easy" meaning, second one, the "no way/impossible" meaning... although for me their writing here seem *almost* identical.

I can see that the first one has this の inside, and that probably impacts the meaning! But can someone develop around it, and tell me what is going on here that makes the meaning differ ?

I've [found somewhere](https://learnjapanesebod.tumblr.com/post/157848565348/%E3%82%8F%E3%81%91-the-word-%E8%A8%B3-%E3%82%8F%E3%81%91-translates-to-meaning) that the "easy" meaning can be deciphered when the expression is used as an adjective, which concurs with Jisho too. But here, it is not as far as I can understand.

Maybe also on a more fundamental level, how such an expression (わけ（が・は）ない）can have two such opposite meaning ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see is a result of two subtle (but basic) grammar points combined.

1. こんなの/そんなの vs こんな/そんな

   こんな/そんな… are (technically not adjectives, but) a kind of single function adjectives, that are only allowed to qualify a noun.

   の has tons of meanings, among which is nominalization. When の comes after 連体形 (form used to qualify a noun) of adjectives or verbs, it can make a noun phrase e.g. きれいなの "beautiful one", 走るの "something that runs". Thus こんなの/そんなの… are nouns as a whole.
2. わけ (noun) vs わけ (形式名詞 "formal noun")

   わけ has multiple meanings as a noun, but aside from that, it is most often used as a 形式名詞, which grammatically behaves as if a noun, but always needs a qualifier and serves as a function word in meaning.

Now, わけ + ない creates two idiomatic expressions:

- **わけ (noun)** (+ optional particles) + **ない**
  "no reasoning needed" = "is no-brainer"
- **X わけ (形式名詞)** (+ optional particles) + **ない**
  "there is no way X", "it cannot be X"

> こんなのわけないよ
> そんなわけないだろう

The first sentence starts from こんなの, which is a noun, impossible to qualify the next わけ. So this sentence can be only parsed as "こんなの [omitted topic particle] わけない".

The second sentence starts from そんな, and it **must** qualify the next わけ, thus this わけ is a 形式名詞. The sentence is parsed as "そんなわけ [omitted particle] ないだろう".

Answer (score -3):

The real meaning of wakenai is "no understanding" or "no reason", so I'd translate your sentences as:

> 「この問題できる？」「こんなのわけないよ」
> Can you do this question? You asking me makes no sense, of course.

With the "yo" translating as "of course".

The second sentence:

> 「N2の試験に合格したんだって？」「そんなわけないだろう」
> Did you pass the N2 exam? That thing makes no sense to me.

So the meaning of "wakenai" differs based on context.

Comment: `You asking me makes no sense...` -- でもこの辞書の例文のように https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%A8%B3%E7%84%A1%E3%81%84/ 「問題をわけなく解いてみせる」の「わけない」だったら？　または、誰にも聞かれてないけど、自分から「こんな問題、わけないさ！」とか「こんな仕事、わけないさ！」って言ったら？